# Angular router.navigate is causing the target component to render twice

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a simple button for entering the app, in my HomeComponent, which simply does:

```
this.router.navigate(['/budget']);
```

This event causes the target component BudgetListComponent to be rendered twice! (also the ngOnInit is also fired twice). This happens casually, around 1-2 times on 10.
I already checked the method is only called once.

main app routing module is like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'private', loadChildren: () => import('./private').then(m => m.PrivateModule) },
      { path: '**', component: NoContentComponent },
    ];
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true, preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
      ],
      declarations: [],
      exports: [
        RouterModule
      ]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

where "private" solves to another routing module, which is:

```
const privateRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PrivateComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        canDeactivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
                children: [
                    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
                    { path: 'budget', component: BudgetListComponent, canActivate: [BudgetGuard] },
                    { path: 'budget/:id', component: BudgetDetailComponent, canActivate: [BudgetGuard] }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(privateRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
    declarations: []
})
export class PrivateRoutingModule { }
```

Dependencies are as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.17",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^12.1.0",
    "angular7-csv": "^0.2.12",
    "core-js": "^2.6.12",
    "firebase": "7.24.0",
    "gapi": "0.0.3",
    "googleapis": "^47.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.41",
    "ng-gapi": "0.0.45",
    "ngx-wig": "12.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  }
```

This happens after a big refactoring and package updates (from Angular 7), i just don't understand how this can happen. I'm pretty sure routing did not change.

**EDIT 1**

as asked, here is the button's html

```
<div *ngIf="loggedUser">
   <button mat-raised-button (click)="enterTheApp()" i18n>Enter</button>
 </div>
```

and the function does:

```
public enterTheApp() {
    console.log('Enter the app');
    this.authService.userHasPermission('app.budget').pipe(
      first()).toPromise()
      .then((val) => {
        if (val) {
          this.router.navigate(['/budget']).then(res => console.log('navigated!', res));
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/timereport']);
        }
      });
  }
```

i've added that "then" for debugging: is always logging once, as the previous console log.
But still, even after adjusting routes as in the suggestions, i can see the target component's ngOnInit called twice.

**EDIT 2**

the private.component.html:

```
  <main>
    <mat-sidenav-container #sidenav class="main-container">
      <!-- sidebar menu  -->
      <mat-sidenav #sidebar mode="over" class="sidebar-container">
        <app-sidebar-list></app-sidebar-list>
      </mat-sidenav>

      <div style="min-height: 97vh;">
        <!-- header -->
        <ev-header></ev-header>

        <!-- main content of the page -->
        <div class="content">
          <router-outlet (activate)="changeOfRoutes()"></router-outlet>
        </div>

      </div>

    </mat-sidenav-container>
  </main>
```

app.component.html is simply:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  template: `
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
```

**EDIT 3**

the budget guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class BudgetGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    console.log('Can activate Budget');
    return this.authService.userHasPermission('app.budget');
  }
}
```

the auth guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  public canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

    const url: string = state.url;
    console.log('Can activate url', url);
    return this.checkLogin(url);
  }

  public canDeactivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    const url: string = state.url;
    console.log('Can deactivate url', url);
    // return this.checkLogin(null).map((res) => !res);
    return of(true);
  }

  public canActivateChild(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log('Can Activate Child route', route);
    return this.canActivate(route, state);
  }

  public checkLogin(url: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.userStream$.pipe(map((u) => {

      if (u && u.role && (['user', 'admin'].indexOf(u.role) > -1)) {
        console.log('acl passed');
        return true;
      } else if (url) {
        // Store the attempted URL for redirecting
        this.authService.redirectUrl = url;

        // Navigate to the login page with extras
        console.log('acl failed', u);
        this.router.navigate(['/home'], { queryParams: { loginError: true } });
        return false;
      } else {
        console.log('acl failed', u);
        return false;
      }
    }));
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show the html code of the button ? is it inside a form ? You also have an unneeded route level, you can totally remove the `canActivateChild` level. When a child route matches, it triggers its parent guards, and generates the parent component too.

Comment: @Random no forms, a plain simple button. Unneeded route level removed, thanks.

Comment: can you show the generated HTML in the browser please ? If you see twice the component, you should see what are the clones' relation. Are they brothers (twins), or parent-child, or cousins ? Can you also show the `private.component.html` and app.component.html too (which should both contain a `<router-outlet>`)

Comment: the clones are brothers, one next each other. Edited the answer to also include the requested details

Comment: well, let's go deeper, can you show your guards ? And BudgetListComponent ?

Comment: guards added as well :D i would not deep dive into the BudgetListComponent.. one thing i found, is that also Services are doubled, so problem must be present before the component itself.

Comment: oh, if you got services twice, maybe that's something in your appModule then, where you're importing twice the router ?

Comment: Thank you, well no i believe that's just fine. I tried tricking the app many times but problem is only generating when clicking on that button. Inserting type="button" on the button suddenly makes the content appear (broken) on the bottom of the page, meaning there must be something going wrong before. The hard thing is i do not get any error in console so it's getting hard to debug.

Comment: if adding type="button" changes the behavior, it means you have a form around that button. and by default, the type is "submit", which submits the form, and by default, it makes a POST request with the content of the form. So yeah, you want it to be type="button" :D

Comment: can you try changing the button to an anchor with a routerLink ? `<a [routerLink]="['/budget']">Click here</a>`

Comment: i ended up using your last suggestion and also moving the auth check from the method to the template and the problem was gone. I think in some cases when Angular fails to build, it just drops the new rendered component after the old, leaving the broken one in the GUI. I also took the chance to clear some dependencies and make the auth service logic more clean and linear. I still don't know the exact reason for the build to fail and what kind of errors actually triggers this weird behaviour. Hoping for the best. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Change

```js
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
```

to

```js
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

And put redirection routes at the end of your arrays.

This might not resolve the issue, but I would guess it's the first step you can take.